# pathping command 100% packet loss

Tags: ping, traceroute, packet-loss, packet-path

[image]

[image]

this is the real example of pathping command.

According to my knowledge:-

1. Source to here column :- it tells about number of packet loss out of 100 send directly to hop
2. Node/Link column. :- it tells about number of packet loss out of 100 which passed through this hop.
3. | :- tells about link congestion.

my doubt is in 2nd image how hop 4 how Node/Link column is 100% packet loss?

how is hop 5 getting ping packet if there is 100% loss in Node/Link column in hop 4?

I know for security reason some router don't respond to ICMP packet. So this is the reason for hop 4 Source to here column have 100% packet loss but why node/link column is not responding?

what if | (link congestion) is 100% what will happen?

Answer (score 3):

You already know the answer:

> I know for security reason some router don't respond to ICMP packet.

Please do not post images of text.  copy and paste the text using the preformatted { } option.

Comment: but why node/link column is not responding? Why it's discarding ICMP packet not addressed to it?

Comment: There could be many reasons, such as access control lists.  But ultimately, questions about networks you don't control are off topic.

Comment: how is hop 5 getting ping packet if there is 100% loss in Node/Link column in hop 4?

Comment: There's not 100% loss.  Node 4 is not responding to pings addressed to it.  But it's forwarding traffic to other networks.

Comment: in image 2 its written 100% in both column at hop 4.

Comment: There's a difference between packets going *through* a router and packets going *to* a router's management IP. They can have different policies for filtering.

Comment: yah but y does router's management IP block those packet which are not addressed to them at hop 4? I am talking about node/link column at hop 4?

Comment: Hop 4 is addressed to the management interface. I don’t think you understand how pingpath works.

Comment: Could u please explain the difference between source to here column and node/link column?

Comment: It’s all explained [in the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pathping).

Comment: I read that doc. what is the difference between these (7  ---     100/ 100 =100%    0/ 100 =100%  72.14.238.53) vs (7  ---     100/ 100 =100%   100/ 100 =100%  72.14.238.53) assuming this is not the last hop.  This is result of one of the hop when using pathping command. I also refer this [link](https://www.clouddirect.net/knowledge-base/KB0011455/using-traceroute-ping-mtr-and-pathping)

Comment: I don't know how pathping works, but those numbers might have been calculated from different packets. If the node/link columns were to be calculated from icmp packets with decremented TTL and the packets have different dst IP from the first tracert part, then the stats could be off. That might also explain the link congestion being 0% between 3 & 4. In my experience, traceroute or ping doesn't always tell you the whole story. If some results of these tools are off, I just consult the packets.

Answer (score 0):

`Pathping` uses incrementing TTL values to first probe a path and then pings (ICMP echo request) each of the path hops for a number of times.

If a hop doesn't respond to ping (100/100 lost) but hops beyond it are responding, then that hop forwards normally but doesn't respond to ICMP echo requests.

It's also quite possible that ping attempts on a hop show substantial loss with a (much) lower loss beyond the hop. That effect is due to ICMP rate limiting.